# Does Deriving probability distributions using the Principle of Maximum Entropy involve with Euler-Lagrange equation?

Tags: calculus, probability, variational-analysis

I am reading the article **Deriving probability distributions using the Principle of Maximum Entropy**, https://sgfin.github.io/2017/03/16/Deriving-probability-distributions-using-the-Principle-of-Maximum-Entropy/

I don't understand this part,

> ## 1. Derivation of maximum entropy probability distribution with no other constraints (uniform distribution)
>
> First, we solve for the case
> where the only constraint is that the distribution is a pdf, which we
> will see is the uniform distribution. To maximize entropy, we want to
> minimize the following function: $$ J(p)=\int_a^b p(x) \ln p(x) d
>  x-\lambda_0\left(\int_a^b p(x) d x-1\right) $$ . Taking the derivative
> with respect ot $p(x)$ and setting to zero, $$ \frac{\delta J}{\delta
> p(x)}=1+\ln p(x)-\lambda_0=0  $$

How does the second equation get derived from the first equation? Is it using the Euler–Lagrange equation in calculus of variations or just the fundamental theorem of calculus of a single variable?

Comment: Yes, that's the Euler-Lagrange equation, but here the functional derivative and the "standard" derivative coincide, since $J$ doesn't contain any derivative of $p$.

Comment: Yes, this involves calculus of variations and the concept of functional derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted in the comments, this is the Euler–Lagrange equation for the given variational problem. Because the given functional doesn’t contain the derivative of $p$, it consists simply in setting the variation with respect to $p$ to $0$.